# Let $C$ be a code of distance $d$, set $t=\lfloor(d-1)/2\rfloor$, then $C$ is not a $(t+1)$-error correcting code

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, coding-theory

I'm reading David R. Finston and Patrick J. Morandi's book [Abstract Algebra: Structure and Application](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3319343955) and hit a proof that I have doubts.

First there are some definitions such as: Elements of $Z_2^n$ are called *words*. A *linear code* of length $n$ is a nonempty subset of $Z_2^n$ that is closed under the addition in $Z_2^n$. We refert to elements of a code as *codewords*. The *weight* of a word $w=a_1…a_n$ of length $n$ is the number of digits of $w$ equal to $1$, denoted $wt(w):=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$. If $v$, $w$ are words, the *distance* between $v$ and $w$ is $D(v,w):=wt(v+w)$.

Then it defines the *$t$-error correcting code* and *distance of a code*:

> Definition 2.4. Let $C$ be a code and let $t$ be a positive integer.
> Then $C$ is a $t$-error correcting code if whenever a word $w$ differs
> from the nearest codeword $v$ by a distance of at most $t$, then $v$
> is the unique closest codeword to $w$.
>
> Definition 2.7. The distance $d$ of a code is defined by
> $d:= \min \{ D(u,v):u,v\in C,u\ne v \}$

Then it states:

> Proposition 2.8. Let $C$ be a code of distance d and set
> $t=\lfloor(d-1)/2)\rfloor$. Then $C$ is a $t$-error correcting code
> but not a $(t+1)$-error correcting code.

I'm fine with the first part that $C$ is a $t$-error correcting code. However, when it comes to the second part, i.e. $C$ is not a $(t+1)$-error correcting code, I found it a bit subtle.

Anyway, the proof goes:

> To finish the proof, we need to prove that $C$ does not correct $t+1$
> errors. Since the code has distance $d$, there are codewords $u_1$,
> $u_2$ with $d=D(u_1, u_2)$; in other words, $u_1$ and $u_2$ differ in
> exactly $d$ positions. Let $w$ be the word obtained from $u_1$ by
> changing exactly $t+1$ of those $d$ positions. Then $D(u_1, w) = t+1$
> and $D(u_2,w)=d-(t+1)$.
> Since $t=\lfloor(d-1)/2\rfloor$ by our
> assumption, $(d-2)/2\le t\le (d-1)/2$. In particular, $d-2\le 2t$ so
> that $D(u_2,w)=d-(t+1)\le t+1$. Thus $u_1$ is not the unique closest
> codeword to $w$, since $u_2$ is either equally close or closer to $w$.
> Therefore $C$ is not a $(t+1)$-error correcting code.

My doubt is: **Is this proving the original statement?**

The original statement to be proved is actually:
**A** Given $w$ and its nearest codeword $u_1$, $D(w,u_1)=t+1$, then there exist another codeword $u_2$, s.t. the distance between $w$ and $u_2$, denoted as $s:=D(w, u_2)$, has $s\le t+1$, i.e. either $u_2$ is nearer to $w$ than $u_1$, so that $u_1$ is not the nearest codeword; or, the same distance, so there is ambiguity.

But here, the logic goes as:
**B** Given $u_1$ and $u_2$, find a $w$ such that $w$ sort of *sits on the bench with $u_1$ and $u_2$ on either ends*, i.e. only changes bits from $u_1$ among those bits that $u_1$ and $u_2$ differ, then $u_2$ is nearer to $w$ than $u_1$ does.

The problem is, **A** and **B** are equivalent, only if given any $w$ and $u_1$, the $u_2$ exists.

But does it? does the bench of $u_1$ and $u_2$ exists?

The thing becomes even more tricky as a linear code is not necessarily $Z_2^n$ — by definition, A *linear code* of length $n$ is a nonempty subset of $Z_2^n$ that is closed under the addition in $Z_2^n$ — so code $C$ can be just a subgroup of $Z_2^n$ such that given $w$ and $u_1$, there is no such an $u_2$!

Where did I miss?

Comment: Negation of the definition does not require that a matching $u_2$ exists to each given pair $w,u_1$. It only requires that there exists a $w$ such that we can find suitable codewords $u_1\neq u_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your misunderstanding seems to be about basic logic, unless I, too, misunderstood. Or, perhaps more accurately, about reading what exactly
that definition requires.

Rephrasing the definition of a $(t+1)$-error correcting code to read:

> A code $C$ is $(t+1)$-error-correcting, if for all vectors $w\in\Bbb{Z}_2^n$ there exists at most one codeword $v\in C$ with the property $D(v,w)\le t+1$.

Observe the universal quantifier *for all vectors...*.

To prove that a code is NOT $(t+1)$-error-correcting, we need to prove the negation of the definition. In other words, the claim to be proved is:

> There exists a vector $w\in\Bbb{Z}_2^n$ such that there are at least two codewords $v_1,v_2\in C$, $v_1\neq v_2$, with $D(w,v_1)\le t+1$ as well as $D(w,v_2)\le t+1$.

Or, in the quantifier language. The negation of the statement
$$\forall w\in\Bbb{Z}_2^n: P(w)$$
is
$$
\exists w\in\Bbb{Z}_2^n: \neg P(w).
$$

Comment: Thx for the reply. Checking your logic, I went back and read through the line again ... then I found where I crippled.